# Is auto-generated id unique across the whole cluster in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is auto-generated id unique across the whole cluster in elasticsearch?
How is the auto-generated id created?

Comment: The `_id` is required to be unique across an index, regardless of how that index is configured. There are performance optimizations in uisng auto-generating, see the section "Choosing an efficient document id" in this [post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/efficient-duplicate-prevention-for-event-based-data-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Is auto-generated id unique across the whole cluster in elasticsearch?

Yes, document id's are unique across the whole cluster. Its a must to avoid conflicts while indexing and searching.

> Q: How is the auto-generated id created?

You can view the source code of the class **TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java** here:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.6/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java

I hope I could help you.